# Differential equation, Cournot competition, Game theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I would like to solve differential equation derived from
differentiating $u_i(q_1,q_2)=q_ip(q_1+q_2)-c_i(q_i)$ by
$q_1$ and $q_2$, resp. and putting them equal to zero,and taking $q_2$ to be
$r_2(q_1)$,the *reaction function*.

So we have a DE

$p(q_1+r_2(q_1))+p'(q_1+r_2(q_1))\cdot r_2(q_1)-c_2'(r_2(q_1))=0$

where
$c_i(q_i)=c\cdot q_i$ for a fixed $c \in [0,1]$
and $p(q)=\max\{0,1-q\}$.

And we would like to compute $r_2:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$.

What is the type of this ODE called, and how is it solved for $r_2$?

The solution should be $r_2(q1)=(1-q_1-c)/2$.

Comment: The problem is completely trivial for the given $c_i(q_i)$ and $p(q)$. But the questions what is the name of the type of this ODE and how to solve it in general,at least under some continuity and strict concavity assumptions, remain.